# How to use css or operator in Python Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I want to find all the a tag that class*='lime' or class*='green' or class*='busy'.

code:

```
bs_tables = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector ("div#tables a[class*='lime'][class*='busy'][class*='green']")
```

But this seems is 'and' operator not 'or' operator.

Any friend know how to use 'or' operator here?

Comment: Some relevant HTML would help for the three cases. Does the `class*` indicate a partial class name like `class="something-lime"` or is it more like `class="someClass lime"? Again, the relevant HTML would really help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying several times I find a solution:

```
bs_tables = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector ("div#tables a[class*='lime'],[class*='busy'],[class*='green']")
```

It works!

Comment: See my answer... I don't think this will do what you want or at least what you think it will.

Comment: @pguardiario ...or the A tag either apparently. My guess is that `.lime,.busy,.green` would even work.

Answer (score 1):

Comma is the OR operator in CSS selectors but the OR applies to the *entire* selector, not just part so you would need

```
div#tables a[class*='lime'],div#tables a[class*='busy'],div#tables a[class*='green']
```

Comment: Thank you. I find a simpler way ,and it works, please read my answer below.